# SharedPreferencies have different values for the same key

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am having troubles using SharedPreferences in an Android app, and I need to get clear on it.

To avoid issues I have created a separated class for all maters regarding SharedPreferences to be used in the app.

This is the class:

```
public class SharedPreferencesClasMiPaciente {

    SharedPreferences prefs;
    Context context;
    private static String PREFS = "MiPaciente";

    public static SharedPreferences getPrefs(Context context){
        return context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
    public static void insertData(Context context,String key,String value){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=getPrefs(context).edit();
        editor.putString(key,value);
        editor.commit();
    }
    public static void insertDataInt(Context context,String key,Integer value){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=getPrefs(context).edit();
        editor.putInt(key,value);
        editor.commit();
    }
    public static void insertDataLong(Context context,String key,Long value){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=getPrefs(context).edit();
        editor.putLong(key,value);
        editor.commit();
    }
    public static void insertStringSet(Context context,String key,Set<String> value){
        getPrefs(context).edit().putStringSet(key,value).commit();
    }
    public static String retriveData(Context context,String key){
        return getPrefs(context).getString(key,"no hay datos");
    }
    public static int retriveDataInt(Context context,String key){
        return getPrefs(context).getInt(key,0);
    }
    public static long retriveDataLong(Context context,String key){
        return getPrefs(context).getLong(key,0);
    }
    public static Set<String> getStringSet(Context context, String key){
        return getPrefs(context).getStringSet(key,null);
    }
    public static void deleteData(Context context,String key){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=getPrefs(context).edit();
        editor.remove(key);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

I try to call this class every time I need to get or insert new SharedPreferences Data.

For now, to retrieve data inside a Fragment, I am using this code:

```
hayFotos =  SharedPreferencesClasMiPaciente.retriveDataInt(getContext(),"hayFotos");
```

To insert data inside a Fragment, I am using this code:

```
SharedPreferencesClasMiPaciente.insertData(getContext(),"codigo_exploracion_actual",cod_exploracion);
```

To retrieve data in an Activity, I am using this code:

```
hayFotos =  SharedPreferencesClasMiPaciente.retriveDataInt(this,"hayFotos");
```

To insert data in an Activity, I am using this code:

```
SharedPreferencesClasMiPaciente.insertDataInt(getApplicationContext(),"hayFotos",1);
```

This way is working but not always, there is another fragment where using the same methods, it is getting a different value for the same key:

```
hayFotos = SharedPreferencesClasMiPaciente.retriveDataInt(getContext(),"hayFotos");
        Log.d("test shared","test shared hay fotos "+hayFotos);
```

At this case I am always getting the value 0 for key "hayFotos".

Is there a way to get SharedPreferences data on all fragments and activities inside an app?

Comment: are you sure you are fetching data after inserting it? and that value is not getting over written?

Comment: @Keshav1234, I don't think the value is getting overwritten, but I will check it now, thank you

Comment: Try using `apply()` which is synchronous instead of `commit()` which isn't.

Comment: @Nicolas, changed, but same result.

Comment: @Keshav1234, apparently the value is not getting overwritten

Comment: @Nicolas, I find it very strange then other keys from the same SharedPreferences are ok, I am getting the expected values

Comment: @Keshav1234,  I find it very strange then other keys from the same SharedPreferences are ok, I am getting the expected values